# Understanding the definition of "preposition"

Tags: usage

In my grammar book definition of **preposition** is given as follows:

> A preposition is a word placed before a noun or a pronoun to show **in what relation** the person or thing denoted by it stands **in regard to** something else

Isn't the sentence wierd i.e. the use of **in what relation**, **in regard to** at the same place?

Comment: How would you suggest phrasing it differently?  Can you also clarify what you mean by "the same place"?

Comment: @JasonBassford - I think the question means, "Isn't it usual to use both those phrases in the same sentence?"